# How do I group messages based on date and sender?

Tags: php, sql

I am making a group messaging system and the dates for the messages are stored in as a DATETIME. The sender is also stored as a id (user-id). I want the date to only show if it's a new day, for example : 4 messages, 2 from 2020 04 05 and 2 from 2020 04 06. It will only echo out 2020 04 05, then each message will echo only the time part of the date (i.e 10:00 pm)

I also want the messages to only echo the username of the sender if he doesn't send a message right after i.e If joe sends 4 messages consecutively, It will only echo out the username of the sender once.

My code :
The get messages function:

```
function getMessages($userId, $groupId) {
  global $conn;
  foreach (showGroupMembers($groupId) as $aMember) {
    $userid = $aMember['user_id'];
    if ($userId == $userid) {
  $returnArr = Array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT user_id, groups_id, date_time, message FROM groups_contents WHERE groups_id=? AND date_time >= (SELECT jointime from groups_members where user_id=? AND groups_id=?) ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 10) t1 ORDER BY t1.date_time ASC";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iii", $groupId, $userId, $groupId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  }
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($returnArr, $row);
  }

  return $returnArr;
}
}
}
```

My send message function :

```
function addMessage($userId, $groupId, $time_date, $message) {
  global $conn;
  foreach (showGroupMembers($groupId) as $aMember) {
    $userid = $aMember['user_id'];
    if ($userId == $userid) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO groups_contents (user_id, groups_id, date_time, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "There was a problem, please try again";
      } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiss", $userId, $groupId, $time_date, $message);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

```
foreach (getMessages($_SESSION['user-id'], $_GET['id']) as $message) {
          foreach (transformIdToUsername($message['user_id']) as $usernames) {
          $username = $usernames['username'];
          }
         echo "<h1 style='margin-left: 5px; font-size:20px; color: #c1c1c1; line-height:25px; width:100%;'>{$username} </h1><h2 style='margin-left: 5px; color: #c1c1c1;' >{$message['date_time']}</h2>
         <p style='margin-left: 5px; font-size:20px; line-height:35px; width:100%; margin-bottom: 35px; color: #c1c1c1; white-space: normal;'>{$message['message']}</p> \n";
       }
```

Comment: This is something you'd do in the UI layer when displaying the data. But you haven't shown us any of your current code for displaying the data (or any attempt to implement the logic yourself as far as I can see), so it's hard to help you. As long as the data is output from the SQL in a sensible order (e.g. ordered by date and then by user), then it should be fairly easy to keep track of what you're outputting - all you have to do is compare the previous row to the current row and look for changes, to decide whether to print the date or name, or just leave spaces.

Comment: how do I keep track of the above rows? And I added how I echo the messages out above

Comment: just store the current row's data into a variable which you can check. When the row changes, then you've got a record of what was in there in (what is now) the previous row

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry if my questions are stupid...

Comment: Literally just copy it to another variable e.g. `$lastMessage = $message` as the last line in the foreach loop. (But make sure you declared `$lastMessage = null;` before the loop starts, then its scope will persist to the next run of the loop)